# Retrieving ids of batch inserted rows in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, race-condition

I'm using SQLite's `last_insert_rowid()` to grab the last inserted row ID following a batch insert. Is there any risk of race conditions that could cause this value to not return the last id of the batch insert? For example, is it possible that in between the completion of the insert and the calling of `last_insert_rowid()` some other process may have written to the table again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`last_insert_rowid()` returns information about the last insert done in this specific connection; it cannot return a value written by some other process.

To ensure that the returned value corresponds to the current state of the database, take advantage of SQLite's [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) guarantees (here: atomicity): wrap the batch inserts, the `last_insert_rowid()` call, and whatever you're doing with the ID inside a single transaction.

In any case, the return value of `last_insert_rowid()` changes only when some insert is done through this connection, so you should never access the same connection from multiple threads, or if you really want to do so, manually serialize entire transactions.

Comment: What about @Zso's comment? He suggests a scenario in which multiple threads could be using the same connection. Would a transaction guard against this?

Comment: One connection = one transaction, so you should never access the same connection from multiple threads, regardless of the threading mode.

Comment: This answer shouldn't be the accepted one, since it talks about **processes**, but the risk is in using **threads**. `last_insert_rowid()` is not necessarily multithread-safe; "multi-thread" threading mode disables mutexing on database connections.

Comment: @Zso The question asks about processes. And no threading mode can prevent another thread from doing another insert on the same connection, and thus making `last_insert_rowid()` invalid.

Comment: @CL. The question asks about "any risk of race conditions", processes were but an example. Answers telling about threads should be given more points.

Answer (score 4):

`last_insert_rowid()` is connection-dependent, so there is a risk when multiple threads are using the same connection, without SQLite switched to Serialized threading mode.

Comment: How does serialized thread mode guard against this issue? Does it prevent multiple threads from using the same connection?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using multiple threads, but SQLite is in Serialized mode by default. It's supposed to make SQLite threadsafe even within the same database connection via mutexes.

Comment: Your original question indicates **processes**, but you seem to be interested in **threads** instead. (Database connections cannot be shared between processes.)

Comment: @maxedison is there a problem with my answer? You're not upvoting it, however it contains one possible answer to your question, while the accepted answer contains none.